# What is the difference between "undergo" and "have been through"?

Tags: word-difference

What is the difference between "undergo" and "have been through"?

> I have undergone a 10 hour surgery to fix my bone fracture.
>
> I have been through a 10 hour surgery to fix my bone fracture.

Comment: There's no significant difference between ***to undergo*** and ***to go through*** in your context except that the former is slightly more "formal", and thus slightly less common (particularly in casual speech among less educated people with smaller vocabularies). People with *more* extensive vocabularies would be more likely to say *I **underwent** a 10-hour surgery*, but that's *very slightly* "quaint" to some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example there is no difference.  However, there are some differences.

For example, one would say

> I **have been through** the worst.
>   I **have undergone** the worst.
>   *( meaning: I come through the worst )*
>
> We **have been through** thick and thin.

but not

> We **have undergone** thick and thin.

Also **undergone** could mean one is still undergoing *something*

> He's **undergone** surgery and should be finished in two hours.

> He **has been through** surgery.

is strictly in the past and is equivalent to

> He **underwent** surgery.